# Moodle PayPal Enrolment on Payment tosses up a superfluous code string that scares users

Tags: paypal, moodle, user-enrollment

I have Enrollment on Payment (through PayPal) working flawlessly, except for one things: when users click the "Select Payment Type" button and the enrol.html popup opens, it has the following string under the PayPal payment button:

{$a->label}: {$a->value}

[screenshot showing oddball code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7R5S.jpg)

I have searched high and low for any information and have only been able to verify that my integration follows all the instructions. The payments are processed; users receive no error. But that line of code is worrying everyone. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a core Moodle string `labelvalue` in `/lang/en/moodle.php`

```
$string['labelvalue'] = '{$a->label}: {$a->value}';
```

Which is being displayed in the fee breakdown via a mustache template in `/payment/templates/fee_breakdown.mustache`

```
<div class="core_payment_fee_breakdown">
    {{#surcharge}}
        {{# str }} labelvalue, core, {
            "label": {{# quote }}{{# str }} cost {{/ str }}{{/ quote }},
            "value": {{# quote }}{{# str }} feeincludesurcharge, core_payment, {
                "fee": "{{fee}}",
                "surcharge": {{surcharge}}
                } {{/ str }}{{/ quote }}
            } {{/ str }}
    {{/surcharge}}
    {{^surcharge}}
        {{# str }} labelvalue, core, {
            "label": {{# quote }}{{# str }} cost {{/ str }}{{/ quote }},
            "value": "{{fee}}"
            } {{/ str }}
    {{/surcharge}}
</div>
```

Which I think is being called by `updateCostRegion` in `/payment/amd/src/gateways_modal.js`

Maybe one of the PayPal settings in Moodle has a null value somewhere, so its not being displayed correctly

Check the value for the PayPal surcharge - if its already 0 then click save to make sure the database has been updated with 0 rather than a null

Site admin > Plugins > Payment gateways > Paypal

Or direct to `/admin/settings.php?section=paymentgatewaypaypal`

If that doesn't fix it, then check the enrol cost for the paypal enrolment plugin

Site admin > Plugins > Enrolments > Paypal

Or direct to `/admin/settings.php?section=enrolsettingspaypal`

Again, if Enrol cost is already 0 then save changes to make sure

And check the enrol cost for the course

Course menu > Participants > Enrolment methods > Paypal

Comment: Thanks, Russell. I carried out each of those checks and nothing has changed. I also tried creating a new payment method (replacing the previous one but with all the same information pulled direct from PayPal) as well as changing the theme. No dice; the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It turns out this is a known bug and they're working on it now: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-77003

Thank you again, Russell.

Comment: Ah, I usually check there too, nice one!